# SSL certifcate in combination with images from feeds

Tags: ssl

My website uses feeds to implement ads. My website is using a SSL certificate, however some of the feeds are not. The image path from those feeds are loaded into my database, then those images get inserted in my website.

This is the warning I recieve for every image loaded through http:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mywebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.feedurl.com/image1'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

*Note: I changed the links of the website to protect the customers identity.*

**My question: Is there a way for me to get rid off the 'insecure image warning' without having to download every single image?** I have tried to load some of the feeds through https instead of http, but because the lack of a SSL certificate most of the images are not loaded at all.

---

**Edit 1:**
My website gets very slow because of the http --> https issue. So a way to make the images secure without downloading them to my server would be an even better solution.

Comment: I don't think if you can do what you want to do because we use SSL for secure the internet and what you want to do is to use insecure data ! and this is the right of users to know about this security issue.

Comment: One solution (which I will not recommend and I will not use myself) is to use SSL only in parts of your website where you don't use this feeds (if applicable), it should be the areas where you collect/send from/to server of course.

Comment: @soheyl. That would pretty much be 80% of my website, which would beat the point of using SSL at all unfortunately. I either can look for a way to change the image url to https or download the images to my server. These are the only two solutions I found so far. If there is no other way I will download every image, but that might cause some trouble for the server.

Comment: Well sadly or not, this is how SSL work and we should be happy about that, because we can truest websites with that.

Comment: Try to put relative protocols like this `//www.feedurl.com/image1`

Comment: @Soheyl That's true. I guess I will try cashing the images first. If that slows down the server too much I will have to download every image unfortunately.

Comment: Good luck then :)